# SQL Query not includes valid result in Left Join with Where Not Equal To

Tags: sql, null, where-clause, left-join, iif

I have a SQL query which does not perform as expected and returns incomplete results. In the query below, valid t1 rows are not included in the query results if there are no matching ids in t2.

```
Select t1.id, t2.code
From table1 t1
left join t2 on t1.id = t2.id
where t2.code != 'value'
```

When removing the Where clause, the results return valid t1.id data, with nulls in the t2 columns

```
Select t1.id, t2.code
From table1 t1
left join t2 on t1.id = t2.id
```

CORRECTLY RETURNS

```
t1.id | t2.code
1234  | null
```

I can get around the issue by adding IIF to the Where clause, however this method is not a viable solution in my reporting tools:

```
Select t1.id, t2.code
From table1 t1
left join t2 on t1.id = t2.id
where iif(t2.code is null, '', t2.code) != 'value'
```

CORRECTLY RETURNS

```
t1.id | t2.code
1234  | null
```

Why does including t2.code != 'value' remove the t1.id = 1234 row from the results? The t2 side of the results are null, and thus not equal to 'value', so shouldn't the row be included in the results?

Comment: Move the t2 conditions from WHERE to the ON clause to get true LEFT JOIN result.

Comment: what SQL version is this?

Comment: Comparisons involving `NULL` are always false, no matter if asking for equality or inequality. Unless you take them into account, `NULL`s will always be excluded.